# React jest Cannot find module '@island.is/core'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Morning, I'm trying to write a jest test case for a component and I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot find module '@island.is/core' from 'src/components/Header/Header.tsx'
```

I think the problem is that jest does not know where `@island.is/core` leads to. I was wondering if anyone knew how to let jest know where `@island.is/core` is?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@island.is/theme": [
        "./lib/island.is/theme/index.ts"
      ],
      "@island.is/core": [
        "./lib/island.is/core/index.ts"
      ],
      "@island.is/utils": [
        "./lib/island.is/utils/index.ts"
      ],
      "@island.is/constants": [
        "./lib/island.is/constants/index.ts"
      ],
      "@island.is/types": [
        "./lib/island.is/types/index.ts"
      ]
    }
```

Here is my jest config from `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules"],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testRunner": " Personal info /node_modules/jest-circus/runner.js",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransform.js",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ],
    "resetMocks": true
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by adding these lines to the package.json file if anyone is having a similar problem.

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
     + "^@island.is/constants(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/island.is/constants$1",
     + "^@island.is/core(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/island.is/core$1",
     + "^@island.is/theme(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/island.is/theme$1",
     + "^@island.is/types(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/island.is/types$1",
     + "^@island.is/utils(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/island.is/utils$1"
    },
```